# how to install modules using a module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I wanted to install few modules when my module is installed. How this can be achieved. I am creating a module which requires few other modules to be installed. I want to install them when my main module is installed.

I have placed all those module folders inside one main folder and I wanted to created a install file to install those modules when this main install file is executed. Kindly provide me an solution to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `dependencies` in your module `.info` file which force the user to enable the other modules first

**E.g**

```
name = "Your module Name"
description = "Your module Description"
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = views
dependencies[] = panels
```

in this example you will force the user to enable `views` and `panels` modules first

Comment: But I dont want to use dependencies. I want to install the modules myself. I have over 25 dependencies and I dont want the user to install all 25 dependencies individually as it is tiring.

Comment: If you enable your module then all of its dependencies which are not enabled will be when you click save. You are given a message which says "You must enable the xxx, yyy modules to install zzz." clicking "Continue" will complete the install and enable the dependencies.

Comment: the users will not install all dependencies individually, Drupal will tell theme i will enable all this 25 module for you do you want me to move on ? if you clicked Continue then all the 25 modules will be enabled automatically for you, is that clear ?